# Is there a way to plot concentric circular color map from a 2D (x,y) data set, where x being the radius of the circle in python

Tags: python

I am new to python programming and learning. I have a 2D array of dataset say “Curve”, where “Curve[0]” are the x values and “Curve[1]” are the corresponding y values. For example, say “Curve[0]” = ([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]) and “Curve[1] = ([-4.45, 3.8, 23.8, 2.9, 7.86])”. I want to plot a circular color map where “Curve[0]” will be the radius of each concentric circular ring with “Curve[1]” being the corresponding values of each circular ring shown in color code. I hope you manage to understand this.

The image should look similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one take on the problem. There are two main issues we need to solve.

First, we need a 2D grid of points `(xs, ys)` where both `xs` and `ys` are arrays of numbers in the interval `[-2, 2]` (since `2` is the largest radius in your example). This can be done by first constructing an array of evenly spaced numbers between `[-2, 2]` by calling `np.linspace` (I use 100 points in the example). Next, we can get a 2D grid by calling `np.meshgrid`.

The second problem is to calculate the color at each point. Since we only know the color for five radii, we need a way to guess the color for radius values we do not observe. One approach is to use interpolation, e.g. `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`.

Altogether, the solution may look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Curve = np.array([
  [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
  [-4.45, 3.8, 23.8, 2.9, 7.86],
])

# get the max radius
max_radius = Curve[0].max()
# get X and Y axes, contains 100 numers between -max_radius and +max_radius
zs = np.linspace(-max_radius, max_radius, 100)
# use meshgrid to get 2D grid points, each of xs and ys is 100 by 100 array
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(zs, zs)
# get radii for each point, 100 by 100
radii = np.sqrt(xs ** 2 + ys ** 2)
# color(r) will give the number representing color for radius r
# fill_value is passed to make sure we can extrapolate color
# from outside of the range
color = interp1d(Curve[0], Curve[1], fill_value="extrapolate")
# compute colors for each point
colors = color(radii)
# show the image using imshow
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
img = ax.imshow(colors,extent=[0, 100, 0, 100])
# set xticks
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 100, 5))
ax.set_xticklabels(np.linspace(-2, 2, 5))
# set yticks
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 100, 5))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.linspace(-2, 2, 5))
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it serves the purpose. Just to add, if we could  replace the x-tick and y-tick values by the actual radii like -2 to +2 with 0 being the center in our example. That would be even nicer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. My gratitudes